# Get client confirmation during loop

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, client-side, confirmation

I am developing an application for my client which will place orders on the web automatically using server side HttpWebRequest/Response. The client wants to review the final step (checkout) of each order in the queue  so that he can decide whether or not the order be placed.

Note: Some one might think

> why not the client decide which order be processed
>        before putting in the queue?

But there are many operations associated with
     the order during placement, so the client left with the only choice in the
     final step.

The flow of operation is as under:

The client selects orders from gridview and press purchase button this call a function which place orders automatically.

Steps:

1. The application gets authenticated to the website where the client wants the order be placed.
2. Finding the item and filling the delivery Form.
3. Proceeding with billing information and finalizing the order.

All the above is going automatically through HttpWebRequest/Response so client doesn't have any control over the order process to stop if there is any problem during operation. For this purpose, the client wants to have a confirmation at Step 3 so that he can choose whether or not this particular order be processed?

**The rest of the things done. My problem is how to show confirmation
    box and if the client click yes/no how to proceed next.**

Pseudo code may as under:

```
Dim orderArray(5) as string 

orderArray(0) = "Order 1" 
orderArray(1) = "Order 2" 
orderArray(2) = "Order 3" 
orderArray(3) = "Order 4" 
orderArray(4) = "Order 5" 


    Step 1: Get Authenticated.

    For i=0 to orderArray.Length -1 

       'Step 2: Item Found for orderArray(i) and form filled

       Get confirmation from client ( a client side msg box etc)

       if client-confirmed then 

         'Step 3: Billing Info and place Order

       else

           'Cancel this order and proceed for next order 
        end if 

   Next
```

Comment: You can use an ajax modal popup for this. Inside that loop just show the popup by a inbuilt method .Show() and ask user for the choice and clicking on the OK/Submit button it will then hide the popup by using the inbuilt .Hide() method and the will continue with the loop. Hope this idea can help you...

Comment: Any working code example please.